Asymptotic behaviour of naive MLE under i.n.i.d data.
I'm working in the context where I have $X_i \sim p_{\theta_i}$ independent and I want to study the behaviour of the naive MLE:
\begin{align}
\hat\theta_n = \arg\max_{\theta \in \Theta}\prod_{i=1}^n p_\theta(X_i),
\end{align}
If we have that $\theta_i \to \theta^*$ is this estimator then consistent for estimating $\theta^*$? And what if $\theta_i \in \Theta' \subset \Theta$ for all $i \geq N$ and some $N$, where $\Theta'$ is some "small" subset of $\Theta$, do when then have that $P(\hat\theta_n \in \Theta') \to 1$?
I'm very aware that this question is vague, and I'm not looking for an immediate answer here, because we probably need strong assumptions. I'm mainly looking for good sources where this problem, or a similar problem, has been studied. Thanks in advance!
